# SFML 2.3.2 integration with Qt 5.7 in Linux

Tags: c++, qt, libraries, sfml

I am trying to use SFML 2.3.2 library with Qt Creator to make a small application.

I have added the libraries with the following code in .pro file:

```
LIBS += -L"$HOME/Libraries/C++/SFML-2.3.2/lib"

CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -libsfml-audio -libsfml-graphics -libsfml-network -libsfml-window -libsfml-system

CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -libsfml-audio-d -libsfml-graphics-d -libsfml-network-d -libsfml-window-d -libsfml-system-d

INCLUDEPATH += "$HOME/Libraries/C++/SFML-2.3.2/include"
DEPENDPATH += "$HOME/Libraries/C++/SFML-2.3.2/include"
```

as it was explained on SFML website: https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Compile-and-Link-SFML-with-Qt-Creator

However, when I go into my file of SFML-2.3.2/lib, I do not see any "-d" ending files.

If I comment out that CONFIG(debug, debug|release) line then I get **undefined reference** errors. If I don't comment out that same line, then I get `cannot find -libsfml-audio-d` type of errors.

Here are the files in my `$HOME/Libraries/C++/SFML-2.3.2/lib` directory:

```
libsfml-audio.so        libsfml-graphics.so.2.3    libsfml-network.so.2.3.2  libsfml-window.so
libsfml-audio.so.2.3    libsfml-graphics.so.2.3.2  libsfml-system.so         libsfml-window.so.2.3
libsfml-audio.so.2.3.2  libsfml-network.so         libsfml-system.so.2.3     libsfml-window.so.2.3.2
libsfml-graphics.so     libsfml-network.so.2.3     libsfml-system.so.2.3.2
```

Some notes:

- I tried changed names from `lsfml` to `libsfml` and that's why it is different from the instructions.
- I tried a different sfml download approach, I downloaded it with `sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev` and it works with **g++** but I could not connect it to Qt (I am unsure about where the library might be located)

I hope I was able to write a "suitable" question. Thank you for the answers!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking. The instructions obviously are wrong: they refer to files that don't exist. Either install the debug packages that include these files (if such are available), or don't refer to `-d` files from your project. Is there something else?

Comment: If I don't refer to them, I get undefined reference errors for the classes that I use.

Comment: Just refer to the non-debug versions, of course (the ones without the `-d` suffix).

Comment: Your explanation is not super clear but I think I understood and I was able to fix it. I'll post the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a messy way but with what Kuba Ober suggested, I was able to figure out a solution. Please let me know if you know a better solution or if this solution was actually the correct way.

I changed my .pro file part to:

```
LIBS += -L"$HOME/Libraries/C++/SFML-2.3.2/lib"

CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -lsfml-audio -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-network -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -lsfml-audio -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-network -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

INCLUDEPATH += "$HOME/Libraries/C++/SFML-2.3.2/include"
DEPENDPATH += "$HOME/Libraries/C++/SFML-2.3.2/include"
```

And life is gud.

Comment: The duplicated `LIBS+=` lines are unnecessary. Remove the `CONFIG(...):` prefix, and just have `LIBS += -lsfml-audio -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-network -lsfml-window -lsfml-system`